# In what comic do several people each get different individual Superman powers?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

I remember reading a comic in the 90s that took place after mullet Superman died by the hands of Doomsday, and even after "The Surviving Supermen", there was a comic about how they extracted Superman's powers and were able to give one power each to about 7 or so people.

For example, the guy who had Superman's x-ray vision had the side-effect of not being able to ever turn it off and he needed the guy with Superman's flight ability to carry him around to look for a bomb.

Does anyone know the name of this comic?

Comment: “mullet Superman died by the hands of Doomsday” — I believe [Mullet Superman is the one who *returned* from the dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullet_(haircut)#1990s), not the one who died.

Comment: My memory's not that reliable, this was over 15 years ago I read this comic lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are referring to Superman Annual #8 - *The League of Supermen* in January 1996 which was part of *The Legends of the Dead Earth* sequence.

The [**characters**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Annual_Vol_2_8) were:

- Digital Copy of Superman's Consciousness
- Fly-Boy
- Heat
- Pounder
- **See-Through**
- Shield
- Juan dePlaya
- Sara Shane

[image]